# Кандидат или кандидатура?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, выбор-варианта

Сейчас на смежном сайте проходят [выборы модераторов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/5), и стало любопытно, а как правильно:

> Выдвижение кандидатов

или

> Выдвижение кандидатур

Например, как мне кажется, если говорить о тех, кого я готов выбирать, то это будет "Выдвижение моих кандидатов". Но если говорить исключительно о себе, то я скажу "Выдвижение моей кандидатуры". Корректно ли моё предположение?

Answer (score 3):

Обратимся к словарям.

**Толковый словарь Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова (1949-1992):**

> КАНДИДАТУ́РА, -ы, жен.
>
> 1. То же, что кандидат (в 1 знач.) (разг.). Неприемлемая к.
> 2. чья или кого. Предполагаемая, открывающаяся для кого-н. возможность стать кандидатом (в 1 знач.). Выставить, снять чью-н. кандидатуру (назвать или отвести кого-н. как возможного кандидата).

> Кандидат  — 1. Лицо, которое предполагается к избранию, назначению или к приему куда-нибудь.
> **Примеры**: К. в депутаты. К. на должность. К. в члены КПСС.

Как видно из значений, разницы почти нет. Однако вы правы в своих рассуждениях, о себе можно сказать только:  Выдвижение своей кандидатуры. "Выдвижение своего кандидата" будет иметь другое значение.

Comment: т.е. если подходит любой вариант, лучше выбирать "кандидат" как более литературный (не разговорный)?

Comment: Да, в первом значении это разговорный вариант.

Comment: То есть говорить "Выдвижение кандидата было отозвано 2 дня назад" тоже корректно? Просто мне кажется, что не очень это звучит. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Можно отозвать и кандидатуру и кандидата.

Comment: В Яндекс поисковике вбейте "Отозвать кандидата", вам придут много примеров. Просто здесь я не могу привести эти примеры.

Comment: Серж, я не стала утверждать правку участника *Зонтик* только потому, что в словарной статье (а ее представляли как цитирование) никак не может быть написание **Кпсс**.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова в очереди "предлагаемые правки", если не ошибаюсь, должны быть варианты "принять и править" и "отклонить и править". Некоторые из моих правок принимались или отклонялись именно так.

Comment: @Римма Михайлова, именно так и было написано. Я скопировал и  не обратил внимание.